# pull combination of 2 tables from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to pull combinations of 2 columns from two different tables from the same database.

ex:table1 has columns

```
Org_Id     Org_Name 
1001       company1   
1002       company2
```

table2 has columns

```
Country_Id       Country_Name 
1                        USA  
2                        uk
3                        australia
4                        canada
```

after creating combinations ,i need to create table 3 which hold the values of combinations...

table3 should have columns

```
org_name     Country_Name 
company1      usa
company2      uk   
company2      usa
company1      canada
```

Note: Using joint we can display what ever we have in columns ,, but i need combinations of both the columns....
please help me this.....expecting your response asap....Thanks you all...

Comment: is there no connection between these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from that how the 'combined' table should detect data, but normally that is done using [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html). Look into that.

Just noticed that in the manual there is actually an example that does pretty much what you described.

Comment: Right, you need a key to join the tables

Answer (score 0):

as described in example these two tables are not connected each other..

then you can directly take join without any joint condition ..

```
     select Org_Name , Country_Name 
       from table1, table2
```

but as per practice this approach is not correct.. you should join tables with connected tables to show valuable result..

Answer (score 0):

After you have figured how you want to join the tables, you could use INSERT ...SELECT

```
INSERT into table3(orgname,countryname) SELECT orgname,countryname from table1,table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new table and insert all the combinations in one fell swoop using SELECT INTO as follows:

```
SELECT org_Name, Country_Name
INTO table3
FROM table1, table2
```